# Print output to text file (.txt) using Python

Tags: python

I want print my output to text file. But the results different if I print in terminal. My code :

```
...
words = keywords.split("makan","Rina")
sentences = text.split(".")
for itemIndex in range(len(sentences)):
  for word in words:
    if word in sentences[itemIndex]:
        print('"' + sentences[itemIndex] + '."')
        break
```

The ouput like this :

```
"Semalam saya makan nasi padang."
" Saya makan bersama Rina."
" Rina pesan ayam goreng."
```

If I add print to text file :

```
words = ["makan","Rina"]
sentences = text.split(".")
for itemIndex in range(len(sentences)):
  for word in words:
    if word in sentences[itemIndex]:
       with open("corpus.txt",'w+') as f:
         f.write(sentences[itemIndex])
         f.close()
```

The output just :

```
 Rina pesan ayam goreng
```

Why? How to print outputs to text file same like I print outputs in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reopening the file for each iteration of the loop so when you write to it you overwrite what is already there. You need to open the file outside of all the loops and open it in append mode, denoted by `a`.

When you finish you will end up with only the last line in the file. Remember to close the file using `f.close()` when you are done with it.

Comment: recommending `a` is bad advice. The problem is NOT that he needs to append on each iteration...he should really just open it once, write what he wants and then close it. Your suggestion of `f.close` is redundant. When you open a file using the `with` syntax, it gets closed automatically when the interpreter exits that context.

Comment: The way that his loop structure is set up, lends itself to using append mode. If he wanted to write it to the file all in one shot, he's going to have to join the list, concatenating in '\n' characters and then write to the file; or something similar.

Comment: It's still better advice than using append mode. But he actually doesn't need to do that...he can call f.write on each iteration as he is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reorder the lines of your code, by moving opening/closing the file outside of the loop:

```
with open("corpus.txt",'w+') as f:
  words = ["makan","Rina"]
  sentences = text.split(".")
  for itemIndex in range(len(sentences)):
    for word in words:
      if word in sentences[itemIndex]:
         f.write(sentences[itemIndex])
```

Also, `print` usually added a newline character after the output, if you want your sentences to be written on the different lines in the file, you may want to add `f.write('\n')` after every sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are listing `with open` inside of the loop, and you're using `'w+'` mode, your program is going to overwrite the file each time, so you will only end up with the last line written to the file. Try it with `'a'` instead, or move `with open` outside of the loop.

Comment: He needs to move the `with open` statement out of the loop...the `close` line is redundant.

Answer (score -1):

1. You don't need to call `close` on a file handle that you have opened using the `with` syntax. The closing of the file is handled for you.
2. I would open the file just once before for loops (the for loops should be within the `with` statement) instead of opening it multiple times. You are overwriting the file each time you are opening it to write a new line.

Your code should be:

```
words = ["makan","Rina"]
sentences = text.split(".")
with open("corpus.txt",'w+') as f:
    for itemIndex in range(len(sentences)):
        for word in words:
            if word in sentences[itemIndex]:
                 f.write(sentences[itemIndex] + '\n')
```